# Is the id of the place, returned by google place api remain constant?

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

When using Google place api functions, for example, nearbysearch, result contais found places. 
Each place has it's id. 
In documentation https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search#PlaceSearchResults , it is mentioned that "id contains a unique stable identifier" and id " is guaranteed to be valid across sessions".

Does that mean that a place will have the same id, until it exists in google db. And if I obtain this id, it will be always referencing the same place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no.  If ID 1 is specified for Place 1, then ID 1 will never be used for another place.  But, theoretically, another place with ID 2 could be created and then Place 1 is merged into it because both virtual places represent the same physical place.  Then, the same queries that were returning ID 1 for this place could now return ID 2.  Both ID 1 and ID 2 would be valid for this place.